# Borrowed value does not live long enough when using async/await

Tags: rust

I am trying to make two async api call and eventually get error [E0597](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0597).

Here is a code:

```
async fn make_request() -> Result<()> {
    .........
    .........
    .........
    let mut result = client.get(uri).await?;
    let some_key = result.headers().get("some_key");
    let next_url = match some_key {
        Some(url) =>  { 
            let some_result = client.get(Uri::from_static(url.to_str().unwrap())).await?
        }
        None => println!("....")
    };
    
    Ok(())
}
```

When I run this code the error "borrowed value does not live long enough argument requires that `result` is borrowed for `'static"

Comment: Which library are you getting the `Uri` struct from? Do they have another constructor method which isn't `from_static`? I'm guessing that method is adding the `'static` lifetime requirement.

Comment: @Jeremy Meadows http-0.2.8.  You are right! When I removed Uri::from_static the error is gone. Could you explain pls how Uri::from_static affects 'result' ?

Comment: assumably `from_static` requires the reference to have a static lifetime, meaning `url` must have a static lifetime, meaning `result` must have a static lifetime. The compiler is trying to help by back-referencing where the reference came from (though can be confusing if you don't see the link)

Comment: It doesn't effect `result` directly, but hopefully the answer I posted helps illustrate a little better what all that `'static` requirement entails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a compile-able example based on your snipped to reproduce the error in the playground, and if you are able to do something like this in your question (for future reference), it usually helps you get more specific answers.

The `Request` passed into the function has no lifetime guarantees, so this will fail with the error you mentioned:

```rust
use http::{Request, Uri};

async fn make_request(result: &Request<()>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    match result.headers().get("some_key") {
        // `url` is a reference to the string in the "some_key" header
        Some(url) => {
            let some_result = Uri::from_static(url.to_str().unwrap());
        }
        None => println!("....")
    };
    
    Ok(())
}
```

You *can* add that lifetime requirement, but that probably isn't what you need, and will likely give you the same error message, just in a different place:

```rust
async fn make_request_static(result: &'static Request<()>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    match result.headers().get("some_key") {
        // because the request is static, so can be `url`
        Some(url) => {
            let some_result = Uri::from_static(url.to_str().unwrap());
        }
        None => println!("....")
    };
    
    Ok(())
}
```

`Uri` implements the `FromStr` trait, though, so you would be best off using that. There is no longer a lifetime requirement, so it can work with any string you pass in, even one which is currently borrowed:

```rust
// need to import the trait to use its methods
use std::str::FromStr;

async fn make_request_3(result: &Request<()>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    match result.headers().get("some_key") {
        // because the request is static, so can be `url`
        Some(url) => {
            let some_result = Uri::from_str(url.to_str().unwrap());
        }
        None => println!("....")
    };
    
    Ok(())
}
```